# reference LONG variable to cell in a sheet

Tags: excel, vba

How to link a Long variable to a value entered in an excel sheet? I want to create large number of rows and although I am able to change the variable directly in the code (e.g. x=100000) but as soon as I link the variable x to a cell (e.g. x = Cells(1,1) no value seems to be recognized and printed to the range.

Comment: Variables will be copied; but not linked. So you must write their value back to the range. `Dim myClng As LongLong:   myClng = CLngLng(Cells(1, 1)):  myClng = myClng + 1: Cells(1, 1) = myClng ` or you can write you own `Macro` to be executed as formulae.

Comment: @houssam What are `LongLong` and `ClngLng`?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed : please see: [longlong-data-type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/longlong-data-type) , and  [type-conversion-functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions)

Comment: @houssam Well, I actually never used a 64-bit version of Office, so that's why. TIL a new thing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In order to simulate the cell being linked to the variable, you would have to add some code that gets triggered by something to write it to the cell.

Dim the variable as `Public` or `Global` (outside of the routine that sets it), so that other subroutines can "see" its value:

```
Public x as Long
```

and then add the code that sets its value to the worksheet in the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event or the `Worksheet_Change` event (depending on how you want it to work):

```
Cells(1, 1) = x
```

If you are trying to set the variable automatically, then here's the opposite. Add this to the `WorkSheet_Change` event:

```
If Target.Row = 1 and Target.Column = 1 Then 
    x = Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. I found the following approach to work best for me.

```html
Sub test()

Dim x As LongLong
x = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, 2) 'e.g. value is 100.000 
range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(x, 1)).Value = "*" 'fill x rows with a * as a test

End Sub
```